# dropzone get current uploaded file information

Tags: jquery, html

I have a very basic question about `dropzone`.

I am uploading multiple files via `dropzone`, they are doing fine, but how can i store the information about current uploaded files?

lets say i have 3 files that i have uploaded. and when they are successfully uploaded, i want to know what were the files that are uploaded currently.
How can i track this information?

### Code

```
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var md = new Dropzone(".mydropzone", {
        url: "/upload/",
        maxFilesize: "5",
        addRemoveLinks: true
    });

    md.on("complete", function (file, response) {
        alert(response)
        if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
            alert('awais');
        }

        md.removeFile(file);
    });
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an array in the outer scope and add all the uploaded files to it:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var md = new Dropzone(".mydropzone", {
    url: "/upload/",
    maxFilesize: "5",
    addRemoveLinks: true
});

var uploaded = []
md.on("complete", function (file, response) {
    uploaded.push(file)
    alert(uploaded) // The files uploaded so far

    alert(response)
    if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
        alert('awais');
    }

    md.removeFile(file);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a perfect idea, i really like it. But can you please tell me, how can i send data from server, for example ID of picture uploded?

currently i am sending jason data, but i can not receive it in response?
how to get that json data?

Comment: The response from the server should be in file.xhr.response, so if you do var json = JSON.parse(file.xhr.response), you should have the json data in the variable.